# com.microsoft.graph.http.GraphServiceException: Error code: SyncStateInvalid

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

```
com.microsoft.graph.http.GraphServiceException: Error code: SyncStateInvalid
Error message: The sync state identified using the request token 'HzWyBB6EZsMOpd9NmgmVnqAnVEMAAAQ9rM8FAwAA' is no longer valid.

GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/6be2c2df-8e20-4f99/mailFolders/AQMkADlmY2YxNTY3LWVhNjItNDFhMS1iZDA0LWZ/messages/microsoft.graph.delta?$deltatoken=LztZwWjo5IivWBhyxw5rAHNeTrUj6tmJCwsicW9zTkZhNFWO0u7VKvvdkBxQHWUvDsSPLMpUBSlb3nEcc_qVbTk1hQlWa3MIyqHvnT47wRA.NIA-bd_JnbZrpOuTHnjHoWWo1K5QPy4CLrFTODjYn9c
Prefer : odata.maxpagesize=1
Prefer : IdType="ImmutableId"
SdkVersion : graph-java/v1.6.0
Authorization : Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJub25jZSI[...]
```

Hi guys, I'm getting the above SyncStateInvalid error, I've done a search, realizing that most people are facing SyncStateNotFound error instead.

Not sure if anyone faces this issue before and knows what is the fix.

I am trying to sync incremental mail messages based on the delta token.

I've tried to paste the same link in graph explorer, and was able to get result.

Comment: That'd indicate your Delta token expired and/or got evicted. How long ago did you get the Delta link before querying back?

Comment: Hi baywet, thanks for your reply! Not sure old the delta link is but likely less than a month old. If it is expired, i would suppose that i should not be able to access the link right?

Comment: Well, depending on the resource, you can get this error if the link has been evicted. That can happen if the link is old and/or if the target resource has a lot of applications tracking changes

Comment: And in which case you need to restart the sync sequence.